# Java connectivity issue with MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

When I am trying retrieve values into a `JTable` it says "cast connectdb to connection", on the line `con=Connect.ConnectDB()`. But I have declared my `Connect` class without any error, and are able to insert values from another form successfully. This is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try{
    con= Connect.ConnectDB();
    String sql="select * from pharmacy";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.execute();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Succesfully stored","User",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  } catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex);
  }
}
```

This is my `Connect` class:

```
public class Connect {
  Connection con=null;

  public static Connection ConnectDB(){
    try{

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms_db1","root","root");
      return con;

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
      return null;
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: show `Connect` class

Comment: `(Connection)Connect.ConnectDB();` is working?

Comment: No,its's getting the error "null pointer exception"

Comment: replace `Connection con=null;` by `Connection con;`

Comment: does db exist ??what is the line error occurred ?did you add mysql libry ?

Comment: Where is con declared in jButton1ActionPerformed() function?

Comment: Where are you getting this "null pointer exception" ? In the Connect class or the method in which you're calling *Connect.ConnectDB();*

Comment: 1)yess i have added mysql library,2)i have declared "con" under my class as "Connection con=null;",3)Getting null pointer exception under the method.

Answer (score 2):

```
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

This is the line you're getting NullPointerException from.. because *rs* is **null**

change this line

```
pst.execute();
```

to

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

You haven't assigned the result from the executeQuery() to the resultSet reference!! and since you're passing a null reference thats why you're getting a NPE. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

try `pst.executeQuery()` in place of `pst.execute()`

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        con = Connect.ConnectDB();
        String sql = "select * from pharmacy";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "
            Succesfully stored" , "User", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); in this line where "rs" coming from?

Comment: ResultSet rs=null; under the class

Comment: Have you try to store the result into "rs" like: ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery(); ?

Comment: yes sir i have done,and now i can see the jtable values from the form which i inserted values,but i want to see the jtable and it's values in another form in the same package, and getting casting error in the line con="Connect.ConnectDB()";.

Comment: i have casted that line like "    con=    (Connection) Connect.ConnectDB();" and worked fine.

Comment: I think this error is come because in ConnectDB function you use "Connection con" and in jButton1ActionPerformed function you use same variable "con" try to change "conn" in place of "con" in jButton1ActionPerformed.

Comment: @AbooSidhu `(Connection) Connect.ConnectDB();` was suggested by me earlier kindly see the comment  of your question